# facebook login dialog not showing permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am doing facebook login. The login dialog pops up but does not show permissions.
My current dialog is like this.
[no permission dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fZq3.jpg)

But i want it like this.
[permission dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFaXj.png)

My code is below.

```
<script>
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
   // var response=JSON.stringify(response);
 //   alert('statusChangeCallback'+response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '1538657022815637',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.9' // use graph api version 2.8
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };


(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1538657022815637";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     // alert(JSON.stringify(response));
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>
```

I tested two different login buttons as shown below.

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-perms="email,user_checkins" data-scope="public_profile,email" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```

Comment: You obviously need to login to Facebook first, before you can log into an app _via_ Facebook. D'oh.

Comment: I am talking about login dialog to login to facebook. It is before i logged into facebook. The dialog has no permission confirmation,ex."company will recieve your public profile".

Comment: You can not get the permissions dialog, if you do not login to Facebook first.

Comment: I have logged into facebook. Now what do i do to see dialog with permission.I don't understand facebook login plugin that much,i just started trying it so I need your guidance step by step slowly.